# Heap Variable or not | * new Object() || Object()?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I got a function and i want to store some objects into a globally list.
Both methods work fine. But do they both create a variable on the heap?
What's the difference between them?

```
vector.push_back(* new object());
vector.push_back(object());
```

ty for help

DrTosh

Comment: Assuming `vector` is an `std::vector<object>`, the first leaks memory (due to dynamically allocating an object that is never released) and the second does not.   Both will add a default constructed object, or a copy of one, to the vector (assuming relevant constructors are accessible and implemented appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both store them in the vector, the vector itself is free in how it wants to store them but it usually uses the free store.

There is a big difference though :

```
vector.push_back(* new object());
```

This dynamically allocates an `object` object and then saves a copy of the object in the vector, the pointer pointing to the newly allocated `object` is then instantly destroyed.

This way causes a memory leak because you do not `delete` the `object` you have allocated with `new` nor do you save the address for later use.

```
vector.push_back(object());
```

This creates a temporary `object` which is copied and stored in the vector and then destroyed, which is the "correct" way of adding objects to your vector.

Comment: in both cases an object is created and gets copied?
With the difference, that the * new object() will not deleted, because its not temporarily?

Comment: @DrTosh Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
vector.push_back(* new object());
```

Don't do that.  You're leaking memory, because every `new` must be matched with a `delete` and you don't call that.  The best thing you can do is never call `new` at all.

This is OK:

```
vector.push_back(object());
```

But in C++11 you can more easily do this:

```
vector.emplace_back(/*any constructor args go here*/);
```

Comment: Plus one for the C++11 approach.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. What have we both missed?

Answer (score 1):

`new object()` creates an *anonymous temporary* variable with dynamic storage duration.

`* new object()` will give you one horrendous memory leak, since you don't store the pointer from `new object()`, you merely dereference it, and pass it to `push_back`.

So **don't** do it that way.

On the other hand, `object()` is an *anonymous temporary* with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar to the following code

```
object* temp = new object();
vector.push_back(*temp);

object temp;
vector.push_back(object);
```

It has nothing to do with `vector`, just no `delete` is called (and you can't)